# zend framework 2 + doctrine2 + DoctrineDataFixtureModule no loading fixtures

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2

hi have some problems with zend framework 2 + doctrine2 and  DoctrineDataFixtureModule (https://github.com/Hounddog/DoctrineDataFixtureModule)
the module is not loading my fixtures
this is my config

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'eventmanager' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'subscribers' => array(

                'Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener',
                'Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener',
                'Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener',
                'Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener',
                'Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener'
            ),
        ),
    ),
     'driver' => array(

          __NAMESPACE__.'_driver' => array(
          'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
          'cache' => 'array',
          'paths' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../src/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/Entity',

            )
          'data-fixture' => array(
             __NAMESPACE__.'_fixture' =>  __DIR__ . '/../src/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/Fixtures',
          ),
        ),

        'translatable_metadata_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                'vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity',
            ),
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
          'drivers' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__.'\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__.'_driver',
          //  'Gedmo\Translatable\Entity' => 'translatable_metadata_driver',
          )
        ),
    )
```

),
the problem is i dont know how set the fixtures path or what exactly key in the array i have to set the fixtures path 
in the documentation the developer says:

> To register drivers with Doctrine module simply add the drivers to the
>   doctrine.driver key in your configuration.

```
return array(
'data-fixture' => array(
    'ModuleName_fixture' => __DIR__ . '/../src/ModuleName/Fixture',
),
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to add the `data-fixture` array to the root of the configuration array, *not* in the `doctrine` array. Like so:

```
return array(
...
    'doctrine' => array(
        'eventmanager' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'subscribers' => array(

                    'Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener',
                    'Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener',
                    'Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener',
                    'Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener',
                    'Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener'
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'driver' => array(

            __NAMESPACE__.'_driver' => array(
                'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(
                    __DIR__ . '/../src/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/Entity',

                )
            ),

            'translatable_metadata_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(
                    'vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity',
                ),
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__.'\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__.'_driver',
//  'Gedmo\Translatable\Entity' => 'translatable_metadata_driver',
                )
            ),
        )
    ),
    'data-fixture' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__.'_fixture' =>  __DIR__ . '/../src/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/Fixtures',
    ),
...
);
```

I'll admit the wording in the documentation is a bit confusing.